# generate mpeg dash segments in specific directory using FFMPEG

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, fluent-ffmpeg

I need to generate mpeg dash mpd file and m4s chunks files for streaming which is working perfectly.

The issue is the segments parts (.m4s files) generated in the app directory (ignoring the output .mpd file location) which restricted by the server, and any generated file should be generated only in specific location.

so is there a way to specify the segments location using ffmpeg?